# A question about a set of prime numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry

Let $n$ an integer sufficiently large.

I'm looking for a "big" set $S$ of prime number $p$ satisfying $10.n \geq p > \sqrt{18n} $ and $p| C_{9.n}^{k-n}C_{8n+k}^{8.n}$ for  all integer $k$ satifying $  n \leq  k \leq 10n$ and $k \geq p $

that means I'm looking a heavy condition  $(C)$ over the $p$ prime $10n \geq p > \sqrt{18n} $  giving me for all $p$ prime satisfying $(C)$ we have for all integers $k$ such that $\max(n,p) \leq  k \leq 10n$ one has

$$v_p(C_{9n}^{k-n}C_{8n+k}^{8n})=\Big[\frac{8n+k}{p}\Big]-\Big[\frac{k}{p}\Big]-\Big[\frac{8n}{p}\Big]+\Big[\frac{9n}{p}\Big]-\Big[\frac{k-n}{p}\Big]-\Big[\frac{10n-k}{p}\Big] \geq 1$$

where $[x]$ is the integer part of a real number $x$.

I think $(C) $ over the prime number satisfying  $10n \geq p \geq \sqrt{18n}$ is:

$$p \in \displaystyle {\cup}_{h=1}^8 ]\displaystyle \frac{8n}{h},\displaystyle \frac{9n}{h}[ $$

I have proved that for all $p $ satifying $ 10.n \geq p > \sqrt{18n} $  and  in $]8n,9n[,$ one has $v_p(C_{9n}^{k-n}C_{8n+k}^{8n})\ge 1$. There are many others prime number satisfying $v_p(C_{9n}^{k-n}C_{8n+k}^{8n})\ge 1$, maybe in $\big(\frac{8n}{2},\frac{9n}{2}\big), \big(\frac{8n}{3},\frac{9n}{3}\big)...$.

Numerically, I have found many $p$ $10n \geq p > \sqrt{18n}$ 
satisfying $ \forall k $ such that $10n \geq k \geq p$ we have $ v_p(C_{9n}^{k-n}C_{8n+k}^{8n})\ge 1$ and $10n \geq p > \sqrt{18n}$.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: As I read this, you want several primes p so that for every k from an interval you want to p to divide something involving k and n. In particular, you want p to divide a binomial coefficient which I interpret as 9n choose 8n. So your set S is restricted to primes between 8n and 9n. Gerhard "Maybe You Mean Something Else?" Paseman, 2019.06.17.

Comment: thanks mr Gerhard for your comment, S

Comment: thanks mr Gerhard for your hel, i need $p| C_{9.n}^{k-n} C_{8n+k}^8n $, $ \forall$ integer   $  k$ satifying $ max(n,p)≤k≤10n.$  $S$ is not restrticted to $]8*n,9*n[$ because  I have found that $\forall p$ prime  $10.n \geq p > \sqrt{18n}, p \in ]4n=8*n/2,9*n/2[, $ we have  $\forall  k $ such that $ max(n,p)≤k≤10n$ one has $v_p( C_{9.n}^{k-n} C_{8n+k}^{8n}) \geq 1$